# libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system does create the cmd_vel topic

Tags: ros2, urdf, ignition-fortress

I am trying to make my own robot, I am using ROS2-humble on Ubuntu 22.04 with gazebo ignition fortress. so I came across this problem where the `libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system` creates the topics `tf` and `odometry` successfully but doesn't create the topic `cmd_vel`:

```
abdosalm@abdosalm-Alienware-m17-R3:~/Github_repos/SLAM-mapping-Robots/workspace$ ign topic -l
/clock
/gazebo/resource_paths
/gui/camera/pose
/model/robot/odometry
/model/robot/tf
/stats
/world/CMP_department/clock
/world/CMP_department/dynamic_pose/info
/world/CMP_department/pose/info
/world/CMP_department/scene/deletion
/world/CMP_department/scene/info
/world/CMP_department/state
/world/CMP_department/stats
```

this is my urdf file related to gazebo plugins called `gazeb_control.xacro`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive" filename="libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so">
        <!-- <plugin name='diff_drive' filename='libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so'> -->
   
            <!-- Wheel Information -->
            <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>

            <!-- distance between centers of the wheel-->
            <wheel_separation>0.297</wheel_separation> 
            <wheel_diameter>0.066</wheel_diameter>

            <!-- Limits -->
            <max_wheel_torque>200</max_wheel_torque>
            <max_wheel_acceleration>10.0</max_wheel_acceleration>
            
            <!-- Output -->
            <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
            <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
            
            <!-- publish odometry and transform of odometry -->
            <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
            <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
            <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>
            <!-- <topic>/model/robot1/cmd_vel</topic> -->

        </plugin>
        

    </gazebo>


</robot>
```

so what did I do wrong, since the topics `tf` and `odometry` were created successfully then the plugin is working but why wasn't `cmd_vel` created?